# Adding element to the end of list

Tags: java

Supposing I have the following ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And I didn't know how many elements were in it.

I then wanted to add an element at a position after the one which is currently the last, something like:

```
myList.add(myList.size()+1, "Hello World");
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: The very first method in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) says about the method `add` which adds an element to the end of a list by default.

Comment: use overloaded add method. Keep using IDEs like Eclipse/Netbean. Get command over IDE so that it will be easy to code.

Answer (score 7):

You use the overloaded [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) method that doesn't take an index to add to the end.

```
myList.add("Hello World");
```